# What do the names 不二夫 and 不二雄 mean?

Tags: etymology, names

I am from Hong Kong. I know Chinese language. I know very little about Japnanese language.

My question is - What do the names 不二夫 and 不二雄 mean? Do they mean "loyal man/hero"?

Links to related webpage in any languages are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/word/不二-617901

Comment: Some context would not hurt. Where did you see them used and how?